# Alter a specific element in an array inside redux toolkit state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

So I'm trying to change a property of an object inside an array in my state.

```
export const changeStatus = createAsyncThunk('changeStatus', async (arg) => {
    const todo = arg
    const response = await axios.put(`${URL}/${todo._id}`, { ...todo, done: !todo.done })
    return response.data
})
```

That is working, it changes my todo in the database, but then when I try to change it inside my state like this:

```
.addCase(changeStatus.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
             const {_id, done} = action.payload
             let newList = state.list
             newList[_id].done = done
 })
```

It gave me and error saying that my list is undefined:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): newList[_id] is undefined

I can't figure out why, since I did something pretty similar to it when adding a new object to my array and it worked fine.

```
.addCase(addTodos.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            let newList = state.list
            newList.unshift(action.payload)
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Array or Object?  Index or id?

```
let newList = state.list
newList.unshift(action.payload)
```

This right here says that `state.list` is an `array`.  It also says that there is no relation between the `_id` of the todo and its index in that array because we are adding new todos at the start of this list and thus changing the indexes for every existing entry.

With that in mind, hopefully now you can see the problem with this:

```
const {_id, done} = action.payload
let newList = state.list
newList[_id].done = done
```

Accessing `newList[_id]` will only work if `_id` is the index of this item in the list.  I don't think it is.  I think you've mixed up syntaxes and assumed here that you have an `object` keyed by `_id` rather than an `array`.

#### Solution

You have a mismatch, so you can change either one to match the other.

If `state.list` is an `array`:

```
.addCase(changeStatus.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  const {_id, done} = action.payload
  // find this todo in the list
  const todo = state.list.find(t => t._id === _id);
  // update that todo
  todo.done = done;
  // note: .find() might return undefined, so you may want to handle that
})
.addCase(addTodos.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  // prepend to list
  state.list.unshift(action.payload);
})
```

If `state.list` is a keyed `object`:

```
.addCase(changeStatus.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  const {_id, done} = action.payload
  // update status for this key
  state.list[_id].done = done;
})
.addCase(addTodos.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  const todo = action.payload;
  // set the todo at this key
  state.list[todo._id] = todo;
})
```